# XCUITest - Test runner never began executing tests after launching

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcuitest

Whenever I'm trying to run any of my iOS automation tests, only the runner app gets installed and none of the tests actually get executed because the executable is not installed. This issue occurs regardless if installing the app on an iOS Simulator or if using a physical device.
When running using the xcodebuild command, I end up getting the following error:
`CoachUITests-Runner (14419) encountered an error (Test runner never began executing tests after launching. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle)`.
I'm using XCode 12.5 and this issue started occurring randomly without any context. No code whatsoever was changed since last time my tests worked.
What am I missing?

Comment: Could you try the Xcode 13 RC and see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm building a large project that seems to need additional configuration before building using Xcode 13.

Comment: hey, did you get this to work? we're struggling with the same issue and have no idea yet what's causing it.
I discovered a crashlog for the simulator saying that somewhere inside MapKit is deadlocking maybe... but not sure why.

Comment: **TL;DR** The 'poor solution' was to re-download iOS 14 Simulators and continue to run the tests on those instead. 

We have the same problem when trying to have Xcode 13.0 (13A233) run our (unchanged) tests on iOS 15.0 Simulators: the app is installed → hangs on the launch screen → fails after a couple of minutes. On both iOS 14 & 15 there are warnings like `objc[46710]: Class FIRAEvent is implemented in both`, but on iOS 15 the log ends with many lines of `LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set` & `LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! yeah, we took the same approach actually, run tests on iOS 14 until we figure out a way... btw, weird that there are not much people raising this issue, I think it must be a misconfiguration on the project, although I don't know which one.

Comment: I'm having the same problems, evenq you to solve this just put in the iOS14 version, I don't think I should put it as a solution, I think we have to see something that can adjust this.

Looking deeper I saw that this is not happening in all projects, I think it may be some configuration a dependency that may be causing the problem.

Has anyone got any solution?

Comment: Had the same problem and in everyone else on my team the tests run successfully.
I tried every possible solution but what worked for me was to uninstall and reinstall XCode.

Comment: I’ve been facing this consistently across multiple Xcode versions. Now on Xcode 13.2.1. Using fastlane to run tests. Not sure what to do. Started happening with Xcode 13

Comment: We fixed this issue by changing the `inherit!` property of the test target in our Podfile from `:complete` to `:search_paths`. For more info see this [Apple Developer Forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691809?login=true&page=1#708476022)